# ¿Cómo enumerar una lista que posee solamente Strings?

Tags: python, lista, string

necesito ayuda con mi código, me solicitan qué muestre en la terminal una lista de mercado en donde se organicen los productos en orden alfabético y que se muestre la cantidad de productos que hay en la lista en forma numérica, sin qué se repita el producto, ya todo lo tengo a excepción de que se muestre en números la cantidad de productos que hay en la lista.

```
lista = []

while True:
    try:
        Item = input("Grocery items: ")
        lista.append(Item)
    except EOFError:
        lista.sort()
        for element in lista:
            longik = len(lista)
            print(f"{longik} " + element.upper())

        break
```

Comment: que te parece usar las funciones `set`, `list`, `sorted` y `str.count()`? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el [método `sorted()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp) para ordenar objetos iterables. Prueba con este codigo como base:

```
lista = [
    'aa',
    'att',
    'baa',
    'att', 
    'cda',
    'ztt',
    'att',
]

items = set(lista)

items = sorted(items)

print('\tMi lista ordenada\t')
for item in items:
    print(f'\t{item}: \t {lista.count(item)}')
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
    $ python ejemplo.py
        Mi lista ordenada
        aa:      1
        att:     3
        baa:     1
        cda:     1
        ztt:     1
```

Answer (score 0):

No comprendo por el enunciado si busca que implementes el output a mostrar en una lista de python o bien simplemente mostrar la lista de lo que elije el usuario. Te propongo la siguiente implementación (si es que entendí bien tú consulta):

```
product_basket = {}

while True:
    item = input("Define the product: ")
    if item in product_basket.keys():
        product_basket[item] +=1
    else:
        product_basket[item] = 1
    # imprimimos la lista sorteada de productos elegidos y cantidades, en orden alfabetico:
    print('Basket contains: ', sorted(product_basket.items()))
```

El código arroja en cada salida:

```
Define the product: Banana
Basket contains:  [('Banana', 1)]
Define the product: Arroz
Basket contains:  [('Arroz', 1), ('Banana', 1)]
Define the product: Arroz
Basket contains:  [('Arroz', 2), ('Banana', 1)]
```